# operator == differet behaviour on wrapper class object

Tags: java, comparison, integer, equality

can Any body explain me what is happeing in the output. 
If == is use to compare two ref. variable it simply check its reference if they are same then it enter in if body, then why the hell 
aa==bb is  equal if creting static method valueOf()  and ee==ff is not equal (which is ok) if creating its object using new keyword ?

```
static void main(String args[])
{
    Integer aa = Integer.valueOf("12");
    Integer bb = Integer.valueOf("12");
    if(aa==bb)System.out.println("aa==bb");
    if(aa!=bb)System.out.println("aa!=bb");
    Integer ee = new Integer("12");
    Integer ff = new Integer("12");


    if(ee==ff)System.out.println("ee==ff");
    if(ee!=ff)System.out.println("ee!=ff");
}
```

Output :

aa==bb

ee!=ff

Comment: An interesting article that describes your problem: http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/02/01/valueof/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `==` comparator checks for object equality!

Since `Integer.valueOf` maintains a cache of Integer Objects with the value -128 to 127 `valueOf(String)` returns the cached object, thus the `==` comparance results in true.

```
Integer a1 = new Integer("12");
Integer b1 = new Integer("12");
//a1 == b1 returns false because they point to two different Integer objects

Integer aa = Integer.valueOf("12");
Integer bb = Integer.valueOf("12");
//aa == bb returns true because they point to same cached object
```

For the comparance of object values always use the `.equals` method, for primitives like int, long etc. you can use the `==` comparator.

Comment: perfect answer. didn't know about the cache thing. checked with 127 and 128 to get different results.

Comment: In your answer "// a==b is true" not false because unless we create a String using new String() method, Strings with same value point to same String Object. You can please run and check once.

Comment: @Ivar, then better give example for Integer, why are you giving a wrong answer to people?. Since this answer has highest upvote people will think it is right, but in reality the statement(// a==b is false) is wrong. Do you want me to paste a screenshot?. See i wont suggest edits but better change the answer. And i dont know how people simply upvote answer without reading complete answer and without checking whether it is correct or not. And if i change the code then I have to change entire answer. That is like removing complete code.

Comment: @Ivar, let me change a code to Integer Wrapper class.

Answer (score 3):

Because `Integer.valueOf` maintains cache of integers from `-128` to `127`

Here is the source code of `valueOf` you can clearly see that it returns same object if Integer value is between `-128` to `127`

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if(i >= -128 && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + 128];
    else
        return new Integer(i);
}
```

so your `==` returns true. If value is more than that then it will always return you false.

```
    Integer aa = Integer.valueOf("1200");
    Integer bb = Integer.valueOf("1200");
    aa == bb --> false
```

You should always check equality using [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method

```
ee.equals(ff);
```

If you add another if with below

```
    if (ee.equals(ff))
        System.out.println("ee equals ff");
```

Output will be

```
 ee equals ff
```

Answer (score 1):

For ee and ff two objects of `Integer` are created on heap hence both of them are referencing different objects so they are not equal when using `==` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`new Integer("12")` creates a new Integer object with value 12. No matter how times you do that you are creating a brand new object each time. That's why `==` doesn't work in the second case.

The JVM maintains a cache of the Integer objects for values that are believed to be used more frequently (-128 - 127). `Integer.valueOf("12")` behind the scene does the same thing (`new Integer("12")`), but before doing that it checks in that cache if for that value the object already exists in the cache, if it does then that's what it returns, otherwise it creates a new one, adds it to the cache and returns it. That's why `==` works in the first case.

Also, for objects, `==` should never be used for equality checks, instead they should be used only for identity checks (e.g. to see if two different variables are referring to the same object). For equality check always use the `equals` method.